# Regressão linear com python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regressão

Preciso fazer o cálculo de regressão linear, porém li que não há a possibilidade de utilizar/instalar o scipy no windows. Há alguma outra biblioteca semelhante à scipy para realizar esse tipo de cálculo? Ou se houver algum modo de instalar o scipy no windows, também é bem vindo! agradeço.

Comment: Já tentou fazer `pip install scipy` no prompt?

Comment: E aí Anderson, tranquilo? Já tentei, ele não instala, dei uma lida no site do scipy e lá diz que não é possível instalar no windows. Baixei uns arquivos whl e tentei instalar pelo pip e não foi também.

Comment: Não - scipy é  o que você tem que usar - tem como usar no Windows sim. E se não tivesse, seria melhor você tconfigurar o Pyton e o Scipy numa máquina virtual (ou no esquema novo da microsoft de ter um Ubuntu hibrido pr dentro do Windows a partir da windows app store) do que tentar ir muito longe usando outros conjuntos de ferramentas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo o que li no site do [scipy](https://www.scipy.org/install.html) roda no Windows sim.

> [Google Translate] Para a maioria dos usuários, especialmente no Windows, a maneira mais fácil de instalar os pacotes da pilha SciPy é baixar uma dessas distribuições Python, que incluem todos os pacotes principais: **Anaconda**, **Enthought Canopy**, **Python(x, y)**, **WinPython**, **Pyzo**

Tenta um desses:

- [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads): Uma distribuição gratuita para a pilha SciPy. Compatível com Linux, Windows e Mac.
- [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/): As versões livres e comerciais incluem os pacotes principais da pilha de SciPy. Suporta Linux, Windows e Mac.
- [Python(x, y)](http://python-xy.github.io/): Uma distribuição gratuita incluindo a pilha SciPy, baseada em torno do IDE do Spyder. Somente Windows.
- [WinPython](http://winpython.github.io/): Uma distribuição gratuita incluindo a pilha SciPy. Somente Windows.
- [Pyzo](http://www.pyzo.org/): Uma distribuição gratuita baseada no Anaconda eo ambiente de desenvolvimento interativo do IEP. Suporta Linux, Windows e Mac.

Comment: depende da instalação do python na maquina dele, se ele estiver utilizando python puro vai ser tenso.. agora se tiver utilizando anaconda ou alguma outra api por cima do python existem estas versões. não recomendo ele desinstalar o ambiente dele que já está configurado para instalar e configurar outro ambiente apenas para rodar uma regressão linear... mais depende muito o fim que ele vai utilizar... como disse o `sklearn` é uma api muito mais poderosa que o scipy, mais denovo depende da finalidade que ele irá utilizar

Comment: e como disse `ele não roda muito bem em Windows`, pode até rodar com pois fizeram algumas alterações de dependencias para `rodar` em windows, porém na propria documentação eles não garantem total funcionalidade, o problema em si não é o scipy e sim as dependencias que o scipy utiliza

Comment: Por padrão o `anaconda` não vem com o scipy instalado, a instalação do scipy é feita da seguinte maneira: `conda install -c anaconda scipy=0.19.0`

Answer (score 3):

Segundo a [própria documentação](https://www.scipy.org/install.html) do `scipy` ele não roda muito bem em `Windows` pois tem algumas dependências que funcionam apenas em `linux` e `mac`

Como alternativa, recomendo utilizar o [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/), ela é uma lib muito boa trabalhar com machine learning, e possui também uma boa documentação além de vários exemplos.

para instalá-lo você pode:

`pip install -U scikit-learn`

ou se utilizar o anaconda:

`conda install scikit-learn`

Fiz um exemplo utilizando o [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) (para trabalhar com arrays) e o [matplot](https://matplotlib.org/) (para trabalhar com gráficos)
Para instalar:

`pip install numpy`

`python -m pip install -U pip setuptools`

`python -m pip install matplotlib`

No anaconda geralmente estas libs já vem instaladas.

Abaixo segue o exemplo de criar uma regressão linear com o `sklearn`

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn import linear_model

    #Logica x = x*10 + acc
    #acc = acc + 5
    #acc inicia em 0

    #dataSet treino
    #1 - 10 + 0 = 10
    #2 - 20 + 5 = 25
    #3 - 30 + 10 = 40
    #4 - 40 + 15 = 55
    x_train = np.array([ [1], [2], [3], [4] ]);
    y_train = np.array([ 10, 25, 40, 55 ]);

    #dataSet teste
    #5 - 50 + 20 = 70
    #6 - 60 + 25 = 85
    #7 - 70 + 30 = 100
    #8 - 80 + 35 = 115
    x_test = np.array([ [5], [6], [7], [8] ])
    y_test = np.array([ 70, 85, 100, 115 ])

    #cria o modelo e faz o treinamento (fit)
    model = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(x_train, y_train)

    #exibe algumas informações
    print('Coeficientes: \n', model.coef_)
    print("Erro médio quadrado: %.2f" % np.mean((model.predict(x_test) - y_test) ** 2))
    print('variância de score: %.2f' % model.score(x_test, y_test))

    #monta o plot para exibição do resultado
    plt.scatter(x_test, y_test,  color='black')
    plt.plot(x_test, model.predict(x_test), color='blue', linewidth=3)
    plt.xticks(())
    plt.yticks(())
    plt.show()
```

Esse código irá gerar um gráfico desta maneira:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue também um exemplo da própria documentação do `sklearn` com regressão linear aplicada sobre testes de diabetes:

[Linear Regression Example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html)